# jQuery: Understanding "event.stopPropagation()" when underlying element has click event set using "find()"

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling, stoppropagation

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="http://wp.pl">wp.pl</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $body = $('body');

    $body.on('click', 'a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        /**
         * Causes the "This also..." never shows, but "Why is..." still appears
         */
        //event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        alert('Should be seen always');
    });

    $body.on('click', 'a', function(event) {
        alert('This also should be seen - same level as "a"');
    });

    $body.on('click', 'li', function() {
        alert('This never shows - and that is ok - because is under "a"');
    });

    $body.find('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
        alert('Why is this shown?');
    });
});
```

Fiddled here: http://jsfiddle.net/g3PEr/1/

The question is: why `click` event set on element found by `find()` fires even when its child element has `stopPropagation()` or `stopImmediatePropagation()`?

---

Please read accepted answer and its comments to know why is this happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter if you specify `"a"` or `"li"` in the second argument - the event handler is attached to `"body"`. The only thing the selector does is acting as a filter. The event handler won't be fired when none of the elements on the propagation path matched the filter `"a"`. And that's it.

So consider your code as:

```
   $body.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $body.on('click', function(event) {

    });

    $body.on('click', function() {

    });

    $("ul").on('click', function() {

    });
```

Since bubbling starts at the bottom, the `"ul"` handler is fired first. Then comes the body handler, and they fire in the order the events were attached since they are all on body.

`.stopImmediatePropagation()` can be used to stop propagation to handlers that are on the same level as well as any upper levels.

The upper levels of `"body"` are still `document` and `window` (window being at the top of everything), but because you have no handlers there you will not observe that `stopPropagation()` has any effect.

Another way to explain it that calling `$("body").on( "click", "li", fn );` is the same as doing:

```
$("body").on( "click", function(e) {
    var currentTarget = $(e.target).closest("li");
    if( currentTarget.size() > 0 ) {
        e.currentTarget = currentTarget;
        fn.call(currentTarget, e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide some more information how to stop firing click events on `ul`? The one solution is to use `$body.on('click', 'ul li'...` but that exclude possibility of using `find()`.

Comment: @TheFrost I tried to explain - bubbling starts from bottom. When you are in a body event handler, the event has already fired on all elements that are below body. You cannot go back in time and uncall those functions... It does not matter what filter you use. `$body.on('click', 'ul li'` is therefore not a solution because it just changes the filter.

Comment: Does it mean I have two `click` events: on `ul` and `body` and that's why `ul li` fires first and then `body a`? Please, don't get nervous, I'm really, really trying to understand what is it about.

Comment: @TheFrost Let us simplify as much as possible. `$("body").find("ul")` is just the same as `$("ul")`. `$("body").on("click", "a", function(){})` is *not* the same as `$("body").find("a")...` it is the same as `$("body").on("click", fn)` but with special filtering done in `fn` when the event happens. [Events bubble from bottom to top](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/images/eventflow.png), so `ul` event handler will fire first. Then body.

Comment: I understand bubbling. I didn't understand why in `<li><a/></li>` situation, clicking on `a` triggered `li` first. Now I get it - the real `click` is on `body` when it comes to handle `a`, and on `ul` when it comes to handle `li`. And because of bubbling, the `ul` fires before `body` - `<body><ul><li><a/></li></ul></body>`.

Answer (score 0):

you are using delegated event registration to register the event handler, it makes use of event bubbling to register the event handlers means when an event happens in an element it will get bubbled upto all the ancestor elements till it reaches the document object.

in your case when you click on `a`, it triggers click event for the element `a`, then it gets propagated to `li` then to `ul` where you have a click handler registerd it gets fired, then it reaches the `body`, `html` and last to `document` object where you have the other click handlers registered so those also gets executed where you are stopping the propagation but already the events attached to `ul` has got fired.

the `li` handler associated with `body` is not fired because the propagation is prevented from the `a` handler in `body`

Comment: Does this explain the difference between the 2 methods of attaching event handlers that he used, and why one does work and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

You are using delegated event listeners so the event handlers are attached to the delegated target, not the descendant.

The first three events are bound to the `body` element and the last event is bound to the `ul` element, which is a child of the `body`. So the handler on the `ul` element would fire first because the event hasn't bubbled to the `body` yet. Once the event reaches the `body` the propagation will be stopped (if an `a` tag was clicked).